# Server side or client side filtering for registration form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First of all sorry for my english writing lvl, im working on it now)

I have created 3 tables in my db LocationDataSchema Countries, Regions, Cities and filled these tables with data. Now i want to create registration page with the following features:

- User choose one of existing countries from the list (filter countries stage)
- After that user can choose one region of chosen country (filter regions stage)
- And now user can choose city that belongs to chosen region (filter cities stage)

Is it good way to send post request after every stage and get viewmodel with filtered data? Or should i filter it on client side? If right way is to use filtering on client side can you give me any useful link, because i have never work with frontend before) Thanks for your attention.

Comment: İf you have big data use server side filtering if you have small data use client side filtering

Comment: You need to expose 3 interface(in mvc project, also know as 3 actions in one controller), one is query countries, the next is query regions by countryId, the last one is query countries by regionid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below article shows the example which suits your requirement

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-call-for-dropdown-lists-in-mvc/